# Navigation in Aurelia appends "?id=5" instead of "/5"

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

I counfigure my Aurelia Router using configureRouter of my app.ts like this:

```
configureRouter(config, router: Router) {
        config.map([
            {
                route: ['users', 'users/:userId?'],
                name: 'users',
                moduleId: './users',
                nav: true,
            },
            //…
       ])
}
```

then I have some code where instruct the Router to navigate to a specific user:

```
showUser(id: number) {
    const params = { userId: id };
    this.router.navigateToRoute("users", params);
}
```

This worked until recently and gave me `#/users/1`. After an npm update from aurlelia-cli@1beta3 to aurelia-cli@1beta5 this does not seem to work anymore, instead generating `#/users?userId=1` and failing to navigate there.

Whats wrong?

Comment: Have you checked their "Issues" list for the latest update?

Comment: Yeah, but nothing to be found…

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that this is because the router is eagerly matching the first of the two route patterns you have and using that to generate the route. I would recommend just using an optional route parameter like so: `'users/:userId?'`. This is covered in our documentation here: https://aurelia.io/docs/routing/configuration

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Does not seem to work. Same issue. I add this to the question.

Comment: You have to switch to just one route. `route: 'users/:userId?'`

Comment: Otherwise, the router will still simply eagerly use the first route pattern you specified.